# Warnings when running an lmer in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a linear mixed-effects model in R using the function lmer, but I keep getting the same warning messages.

I am attempting to analyze the effects of graded air density, thorax temperature (main effects), and hive selection (random effect) on flight metabolic rate in honey bees. There looks like there is a strongly significant effect of this "aerial treadmill" I've developed, I just need to figure out the stats to back up my claims.

Attached is my code:

```
    #Loading my dataset
    tread<-read.csv("Beetreadmill 35C 1.288-0.441 - stats.csv", head=TRUE)

    #To look at the headers of your data
    names(tread)

    #To look at the structure of the data
    str(tread)

    #To look at the summary of this dataset
    summary(tread)


    #To run a linear mixed-effects model, install package "lme4"
    install.packages("lme4")
    #Load "lme4"
    library("lme4")

    #Test data for normality
    shapiro.test(tread$VCO2..ml.h.)
    #Normal
    shapiro.test(tread$Tthoroax)
    #Normal
    shapiro.test(tread$Body.mass)
    #Normal

    ## Looking at the significance of the random effects ##

    #Running a (lmer) model (full model)
    lm1<-lmer(VCO2..ml.h.~Mix+Tthoroax+(1|Hive),data=tread)
```

This code outputs

Here's the Warning Messages output:

```
    Warning messages:
    1: In class(object) <- "environment" :
      Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
    2: In class(object) <- "environment" :
      Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
```

Being self taught, I'd appreciate any help with figuring out how to get past this hurdle.

Comment: Someone just asked this question of the lme4 maintainers. (I didn't see this the first time around.)  I had never seen this warning before today, and wonder if it's RStudio-related; I can reproduce it in RStudio, but not repeatably, and am guessing (wildly) that it might have something to do with the display in the environment pane? I **suspect** it's harmless but don't know (since I don't yet know what's causing it).

Comment: linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65718024/setting-classx-to-environment-sets-attribute-to-null-result-will-no-longer