# bug in lme4 package with anova()

Tags: r, lme4

```
library(Matrix)
library(lme4)


data <- lme4::sleepstudy

model1 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, data = data)
model2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1+Days+(1+Days|Subject), data = data)
summary(model1)
summary(model2)
anova(model1, model2)
```

[image]
[image]

So I needed to update R to 4.0.2 and now comparing mixed effects models using the `anova` function returns an error. The error seems to appear when I assign the model because in the global environment it says "object with null pointer". The error seems only to appear using `lmer` and not with `lm`. Can anybody tell me how to fix this? I need at least R version 4.0.0 (my professor writes scripts that require this version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted solution (explicitly call `lme4::anovaLmer()`) works, but the actual problem here is that if you want to run `anova()` comparing a(n) `[g]lm` model and a(n) `[g]lmer` model, **you need to put the [g]lmer model first in the list of arguments**, <because ... boring technical details: S3 method dispatch blah blah blah ...>. (This should be documented, and isn't that I can tell.) For your example,

```
anova(model2,model1)
```

works fine!

The  "object with null pointer" error is a red herring: unrelated, mysterious, probably RStudio-related, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365389/warnings-when-running-an-lmer-in-r) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211186/glmer-models-in-rstudio-run-but-show-object-with-null-pointer-in-the-global-en) (neither is answered ...)

Answer (score 2):

You could directly call the corresponding `anova` method from the `lme4` package.

```
lme4:::anovaLmer(model1, model2)
# refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
# Data: data
# Models:
# model1: Reaction ~ Days
# model2: Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days | Subject)
#        npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
# model1    3 1906.3 1915.9 -950.15   1900.3                         
# model2    6 1763.9 1783.1 -875.97   1751.9 148.35  3  < 2.2e-16 ***
#   ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, this didn't work in e.g. `R 3.6.3` either!

Comment: Thank you! This works for the model comparison. Any ideas why the class of the random effects model is "object with null pointer"? I work with random effects models frequently and I am afraid this will cause problems in the future.

Comment: @Lea I'm not sure what you mean, `class(model2)` gives me `[1] "lmerMod"; attr(,"package"); [1] "lme4"`. R version 4.0.2.

Comment: Thank you again for answering and helping me out. Maybe I'm just expressing myself poorly. I'm sorry. I put the picture of the global environment in the thread. And unlike Model1, Model2 is not a S3 object but a S4 object. And in the enviroment marked as "object with null pointer".

Comment: @Lea Hmm seems like an _RStudio_  (not _R_ ) bug to me, because R doesn't have that feature. I seldom use the "environment", just abusing RStudio for it's code-wrapping feature:) Anyway I've often worked with S4 objects and can't remember facing a related issue.

Comment: You mean by clicking on the checkmark? I see! Sorry I am new to posting questions here myself :) Thank you!

Comment: @Lea Yess, you did well, I admit the abundance of answer handling features is not very straightforward for new users at the moment :D