# glmer models in Rstudio run but show <Object with null pointer> in the global environment

Tags: r, lme4

I am using RStudio to create some logistic regression models based on data I collected. I created several different models using `glmer()` and they worked fine until a few weeks ago. Now when I run the same models using the same data and `glmer()` I get `<Object with null pointer>` in the `Global Environment`, which has never happened before. But there are no problems with the models, no warnings, nothing.
When I run the other set of models using `lrm()` the null pointer problem does not happen. So I suspect the problem might be with the `glmer()` function itself or something with the `lme4` package.
Tried updating R version and packages according to some answers I found here to similar problems, but got the same results (now running R version 4.0.2 on OS 10.14.6).

Also, when I try to plot the models’ predictions (and that goes for any of the models) using `plot_model()` I get this, which also did not happen before

```
 Warning message:Some model terms could not be found in model data. You probably need to load the data into the environment.
```

Don’t know if the problems are related or not, but they both started showing up recently. Tried using R and ran all of it there too. Same problems.
Can someone please help? I am very new here, so if I did not provide enough information please let me know and I’ll be happy to provide whatever else is needed.

Comment: I don't think this necessarily answers your question, but may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770580/r-version-4-0-2-lm4-package-lmer-bug

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug. There really are no pointers on lmer objects. Thats not an issue for you. Its not whats causing the `plot_model` error. If you provide us some data we can help you with that as well.

Comment: hi, thank you! what data do you need? the model?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the warning message and the viewing problem are unrelated. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365389/warnings-when-running-an-lmer-in-r