# Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object

Tags: r

Afer having created an lmer model:

```
my_m = lmer(y ~ x1*x2 + (1|id) + (1|tp), data=my_data)
```

I now want to extract the conditional modes of the random effects by running:

```
ranef(my_m)
```

I got the warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In class(object) <- "environment" :
  Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
2: In class(object) <- "environment" :
  Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; result will no longer be an S4 object
```

and no other output.

Do you now how can I solve these warnings?
(I got the same when running influence command from influence.ME library)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what sort of object is `my_data`? Is it a `data.frame` or something else? (You can run `class(my_data)` and paste the results into your answer)

Comment: It was giving me the same warning output.

Now, I rebooted my computer and the warnings seem to be disappeared.

Comment: ok --- chances are that something was wrong with `my_data` rather than with any of the functions you called on it.

Comment: I think this is RStudio-related. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770580/r-version-4-0-2-lm4-package-lmer-bug?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211186/glmer-models-in-rstudio-run-but-show-object-with-null-pointer-in-the-global-en?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365389/warnings-when-running-an-lmer-in-r