# <Object with null pointer> appears on R Studio environment

Tags: r, null, logistic-regression, lme4, null-pointer

I am a beginner and occasional R user, and I am trying to build a logistic regression model using the glmer() function from the lme4 package. My predictor variables are binary.

I am currently selecting which variables to include in the final model and for that, I am running a single-variable model for each variable.

However, for every model created, the message "Object with null pointer" shows up in the environment.

I can run the summary of every model just fine, and I get no warnings in my output.

What does "Object with null pointer" mean? I would be grateful if someone could shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example.https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This is likely just a display issue with RStudio. *lme4* uses the "S4" system for R objects, which is implemented by the *methods* packages. This system is more complex than the more common "S3" system, and RStudio's system for probing objects to display the object type in the Environment pane can sometimes be tripped up depending on exactly how you loaded *lme4* or created the models. If `print()` and `summary()` work fine for the model, there isn't anything to worry about. You might even find that the Environment pane display is fixed if you run `print()` or `summary()` for the object and/or click the Refresh button in the upper right corner of the Environment pane in RStudio.

Similar discussions of this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4741 and https://github.com/ropensci/magick/issues/70

Comment: Also discussed @ https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/619, w/ links to prev SO questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770580/r-version-4-0-2-lm4-package-lmer-bug?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365389/warnings-when-running-an-lmer-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211186/glmer-models-in-rstudio-run-but-show-object-with-null-pointer-in-the-global-en?noredirect=1&lq=1), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65718024/setting-classx-to-environment-sets-attribute-to-null-result-will-no-longer#comment116852629_65718024)

Comment: I just commented (linking here) at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4741

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben!